# Maven: NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: maven, spring-test

I have a classpath issue.

- Background: Building and running a Spring WebApp.
- Originally it was
  one big project including dao/service/controller/webapp.
- I have just
  broken my project into a maven module project essentially splitting
  the webapp from the dao and service layers.
- Now my webapp junit tests
  do not run.
- The junit code has not changed and I don't think the
  dependencies have changed (albeit shifted around).
- Spring-test is in
  my local repository.
- Spring-test is in my unit test runtime classpath (used mvn debug logging to check)
- I have no other classpath issues. All dao module tests run fine

However, I  get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.
```

I will post my parent and child pom.xml. If anyone has a suggestion, I'd be very grateful.

**Parent Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jake</groupId>


    <artifactId>prototype3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>prototype3.model</module>
        <module>prototype3.service</module>
        <module>prototype3.testadmin.webapp</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <webflow.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</webflow.version>
        <internalrepo.dir>C:\Users\jake\_servers\internalRepository</internalrepo.dir>
    </properties>


    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
            <url>file://${internalrepo.dir}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Web Flow -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>${webflow.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>


            <!-- javax -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Spring ORM support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- -hibernate -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple 
                backend -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                <version>4.0</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <type>maven-plugin</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- thymeleaf -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
                <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

<!--  Our Own-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jake</groupId>
                <artifactId>prototype3.model</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jake</groupId>
                <artifactId>prototype3.service</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>



        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Child Pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>jake</groupId>
        <artifactId>prototype3</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>prototype3.testadmin.webapp</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <deploy.directory>C:\Users\jake\_servers\tc8\webapps</deploy.directory>
        <deploy.name>prototype3</deploy.name>
        <l4j.test>C:\Users\jake\__workspace\prototype3\prototype3.testadmin.webapp\src\main\resources</l4j.test>
        <webinf.dir>C:\Users\jake\__workspace\prototype3\prototype3.testadmin.webapp\WebContent\WEB-INF</webinf.dir>
        <devroot.directory>C:\Users\jake\__workspace\prototype3\prototype3.testadmin.webapp\</devroot.directory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web Flow -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- javax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Our own -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jake</groupId>
            <artifactId>prototype3.model</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jake</groupId>
            <artifactId>prototype3.service</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <outputDirectory>${deploy.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- <resource> <directory>src\main\resources</directory> </resource> -->
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <DependencyConvergence />
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/A01TestSuite.java</include>
                        <include>**/ServiceTestSuite.java</include>
                        <include>**/ZFlowTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${webinf.dir}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <log4j.configuration>file:${l4j.test}/log4j.test.properties</log4j.configuration>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${deploy.directory}/${deploy.name}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${devroot.directory}/target</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${deploy.directory}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${deploy.name}.war</include>
                                <include>${deploy.name}</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>${deploy.name}</finalName>
    </build>




</project>
```

**UPDATE**

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE! - in jake.prototype2.test.testrunner.ServiceTestSuite
>   initializationError(jake.prototype2.test.service.UserAdminServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.(Suite.java:10

Comment: can you run `mvn dependency:tree` to verify if spring-test is actually there in the final effective POM of your project?

Comment: It's there. Also, all code compiles, but tests don't run.
Thanks for the tip, though. That's a very useful mvn utility to know about

Comment: I have recreated the same structure locally, except the model and service modules, and created a dummy junit test with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and it runs fine, no NoClassDefFoundError error. Are you sure it comes from the webapp module and not from the service or model module? In the parent you correctly set dependencies on dependenciesManagement, which also means you need to re-declare them in each child module (as you do in the webapp one) otherwise it will not be part of the module classpath. I would suggest to check the dependencies of other modules as well.

Comment: Yes, I am absolutley certain this is coming from the webapp module

Comment: We need to see the full stack trace; otherwise, it's just a stab in the dark. In other words, what class definition is not found?

Comment: @Sam Brannen. Added the stack trace but hit 30,000 character limit so trimmed a little.

Any insight you have would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In a comment you've said that project compiles, but tests don't run. Maven-surefire-plugin may be the culpit (as it was in my case).
I was getting the same error, but after a little digging I knew that:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.
```

was caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringJUnit4ClassRunner requires JUnit 4.12 or higher.
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>
```

which was thrown because maven-surefire-plugin wasn't picking test framework provider from the classpath but instead supplied its own outdated junit provider.

I get rid of the error by specifying JUnit artifact name:

```
<plugins>
...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>{your.surefire.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <junitArtifactName> junit:junit:{your.junit.version} </junitArtifactName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Comment: This is the fix for spring boot `1.4.3.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 28):

I dont know why but in my case spring-boot-starter-test comes with junit 4.10 and I find that is compiled with 4.12, so after add

```
 <dependency> 
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version> 
</dependency>
```

Works fine. Maybe a misconfiguration in pom of spring-boot

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: In addition to this I also had to bump slf4j to <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>

Answer (score 8):

For anyone looking at this I had a similar problem and the issue had to do with a logging impl conflict that was pulled in from maven transitive dependencies in spring boot.  Once I excluded spring-boot-starter-logging it fixed the issue.

SpringJUnit4ClassRunner most likely wasn't able to initialize in the classloader from the logging conflict and the NoClassDefFoundError was thrown at another point in the code because of that.

Comment: awesome. When I tried to run the failing testcase in Intellij it told me about the 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path' And hidden in the stacktrace it showed: 'at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:96)
 at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)'

Comment: I imported a dependency with it's own logging dependencies which screwed up the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.
Excluding them helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not an answer to my question.

The solution was to break the project up in stages.

- First, I created three standalone projects and ran the relevant unit tests on each. (Obviously this has to be done in the correct order to ensure dependency)
- Second, I created the parent pom and depency management.
- Third, I brought each standalone project under the paren one by one. I gradually reduced the child pom  dependencies through an iterative series of testing.

I still have no idea why the above structure failed. However, since everything now works, there is no reason to continue reduction until I finally break my webapp again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this. I just updated the version from 3.0.7.RELEASE to 3.1.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in Spring Boot. I just changed the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 1.5.6.RELEASE to 1.5.10.RELEASED.

This spring boot version already contains the class below:

org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Answer (score 0):

I used springmockk dependency, which caused those errors.
I fixed it by using a older version of it, because the newest version wasn't compatible with my older Springboot version.